# copy last row from one excel file into another

Tags: vba

I need to copy the last row from one excel file into another. I calculate the last row that contains data and store it in the variable iLastRow.

```
Dim wsProduct As Worksheet
With wsProduct
    (iLastRow).Copy
End With
Set exportFile = Workbooks.Open("C:\data.xlsx")
With exportFile.Sheets("exportsheet")
'Paste the copied row on the iLastRow here
End With
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is by no means the answer you are looking for.  However, you do realize you can record the Actions/VBA you are looking for from Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution.  There are a few things I need to note after the code.  The main idea here is simply set the sheet names.  Get the last row on each sheet, and copy the data from one sheet to the other, directly setting the values as opposed to copy/paste.  The whole copy takes place in a simple 3 line loop.

```
'---COPY ENTIRE ROW---  Loop through Cells by column
For lCol = 1 To lastCol
    s2Sheet.Cells(nextS2Row, lCol) = s1Sheet.Cells(lastS1Row, lCol)  
Next lCol
```

**TESTED:**

```
Private Sub LastRowToExport()

Dim lastS1Row As Long       'Last Source Row
Dim nextS2Row As Long       'Next Target Row
Dim lastCol As Long         'Last Column on Source Sheet
Dim s1Sheet As Worksheet, s2Sheet As Worksheet
Dim source As String        'Source worksheet name
Dim target As String        'Target worksheet name
Dim path As String

    '---SET SHEET NAMES HERE---
    source = "Product"     'Source Worksheet Name
    path = "C:\data.xlsx"  'Target File Path including file name and extension
    target = "exportsheet" 'Target Worksheet Name

    'WARNING - THIS LINE WILL DISABLE NORMAL BREAKING - IN CASE OF LOOP
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled    'Disables breaking when opening new book    

    'Define worksheets
    Set s1Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(source)           'Source Sheet
    Set s2Sheet = Workbooks.Open(path).Sheets(target)   'Target Sheet

    'Get the last row on each sheet and set the NEXT Row on the target.  Also total columns.
    lastS1Row = s1Sheet.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row       
    nextS2Row = s2Sheet.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1   
    lastCol = s1Sheet.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column  'Headers in Row 1

    '---COPY ENTIRE ROW---  Loop through Cells by column
    For lCol = 1 To lastCol
        s2Sheet.Cells(nextS2Row, lCol) = s1Sheet.Cells(lastS1Row, lCol)  
    Next lCol

    'WRAP UP, SAVE EXPORTED SHEET, REACTIVATE SOURCE SHEET
    s2Sheet.Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    s1Sheet.Activate

End Sub
```

**BEFORE:**

[image: BEFORE]

**AFTER:**

[image: AFTER]

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**
When running the code above, there will be a break when opening the second workbook.  In order to avoid that, you can add this line:  already in code above

```
'WARNING - THIS LINE WILL DISABLE NORMAL BREAKING - IN CASE OF LOOP
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled    'Disables breaking when opening new book
```

This means that if you were to have an infinite loop, you wouldn't be able to escape it using normal means.  This code will not generate an infinite loop, as I've tested it, but you need to know this about it, so if you or anyone attempts to use it in another context, know that it has that potential and use it sparingly.

If you don't wish to add that line, you will be prompted to "CONTINUE, END, DEBUG" and choosing continue will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

To find the last row IN YOUR DESTINATION FILE, you would use the code:

```
Dim DestLast as Long
DestLast = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'must add one to get to the BLANK row
```

Then:

```
.Range("A" & DestLast).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```